# Wordle code doesn't work properly? Python 3.10.7

Tags: python, python-3.x, wordle-game

I'm currently writing a small Wordle game, which analyzes a guess word against a randomly selected word from a dictionary; however, there's an issue with it.

Here's my code:

```
SQUARES = {
    'correct_place': '',
    'correct_letter': '',
    'incorrect_letter': '⬜'
}

def check_guess(guess: str, word: str):
    guessed = []
    wordle_pattern = []
    for i, letter in enumerate(guess):
        if word[i] == guess[i]:
            guessed.append(letter)
            wordle_pattern.append(SQUARES['correct_place'])
        elif (word.count(guess[i]) == 1 and guess[i] not in guessed and guess.count(guess[i]) == 1) or (word.count(guess[i]) > 1 and guessed.count(guess[i]) < word.count(guess[i])):
            guessed.append(letter)
            wordle_pattern.append(SQUARES['correct_letter'])
        else:
            guessed.append(letter)
            wordle_pattern.append(SQUARES['incorrect_letter'])
    return ''.join(wordle_pattern)
```

This code mostly works, but it has a problem, in which it breaks down whenever the guess word has a repeated letter; for example:

```
print(check_guess(guess='burbs', word='urban'))
```

Prints `⬜⬜⬜` instead of the intended `⬜⬜`.

I've tried adding many conditions to fix it; however, none of them seem to work.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem. Your code returns EGEGG for me where E is incorrect letter and G is correct place. But why you expect the first letter "r" to be incorrect letter? pager has an r at the end, so r should be painted yellow as it does. To me it looks like the program works correctly but what you expect as result is incorrect.

Comment: I've edited the question to include a reproducible problem; guess I managed to fix the old one somehow, but this one definitely isn't working as intended. And yes, the program works pretty well, but the result is what matters for me, since it's pretty much the interface which a player sees.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the best I came up with (2.0):

```
SQUARES = {
    'correct_place': '',
    'correct_letter': '',
    'incorrect_letter': '⬜'
}

def check_guess(guess: str, word: str):
    wordle_pattern = []
    word_list = [*word]
    temp = ''
    for i, letter in enumerate(guess):
        if __is_correct_place(word[i], letter):
            wordle_pattern.append(SQUARES['correct_place'])
            word_list[i] = '/'
            temp += '_'
        else:
            wordle_pattern.append(SQUARES['incorrect_letter'])
            temp += letter
    for i, letter in enumerate(temp):
        if letter in word_list:
            wordle_pattern[i] = SQUARES['correct_letter']
            word_list.remove(letter)
    return ''.join(wordle_pattern)

def __is_correct_place(letter: str, guessed_letter: str):
    return letter == guessed_letter
```

Comment: It unfortunately doesn't work for all words (check my comment on tabeqc's answer).

Comment: I think I fixed the error. I had to divide into two for loops, but for 5 letter words it's not gonna be a big deal

Comment: Still not working; for example, it breaks down at `check_guess(guess='peter', word='pager')`.

Comment: My fault, using `word_list = word_list[:i] + word_list[i+1:]` only work for a single removal, because the length of the word change and so the index. I think I fixed

Comment: Been play-testing it for a while now, and seeing if something breaks, but nothing has so far! I'd say it works pretty well :) Thank you.

Comment: So glad to hear that!! ;)

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your mentioned output, as running your code returns your desired EGEGG on my machine.

However, as @Sembei Norimaki mentioned, YGEGG should be the correct output, where E is incorrect letter, G is correct place and Y is incorrect place.

It seems like your conditions to check for incorrect place are unnecessary complicated, as you only need to check whether the current letter of the guessed word appears anywhere in the word.

Here is a refactored version that delivers the desired output YGEGG for

```
print(check_guess(guess='raver', word='pager'))
```

```
SQUARES = {
    'correct_place': '',
    'correct_letter': '',
    'incorrect_letter': '⬜'
}

def check_guess(guess: str, word: str):
        wordle_pattern = []
        for i, letter in enumerate(guess):
            if __is_correct_place(word[i], letter):
                wordle_pattern.append(SQUARES['correct_place'])
                continue
            if __is_correct_letter(word, letter):
                wordle_pattern.append(SQUARES['correct_letter'])
                continue
            wordle_pattern.append(SQUARES['incorrect_letter'])
        return ''.join(wordle_pattern)

def __is_correct_place(letter: str, guessed_letter: str):
    return letter == guessed_letter

def __is_correct_letter(word: str, guessed_letter: str):
    return word.count(guessed_letter) >= 1
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Unfortunately, this breaks down (so does imburningbabe's) for other words, such as: `print(check_guess(guess='eagle', word='veals'))`. The two`e`s get highlighted as yellow, even though `veals` only has one `e`.